# system.tbs file too big

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MYSQL database of about 25GB size, that presents a file of 17GB size with the name **"system.tbs"** (it is present in the "data" root, outside of any database).

I don't find many references to this file, what does this file contain and why is it so big? Is it normal that is has this enormous size? Is there a way of reducing its size? I have checked in similar databases and the size of this file is less than 1GB.

Comment: I've never heard of this file or of `.tbs`. Are you sure MySQL is making this? You don't have some other service producing it?

Comment: Also you tag both MySQL and MariaDB. Which is it? What version? What platform? Give details. You know how this works

Comment: I've also never heard of `system.tbs` or any other file with a `.tbs` extension. I can't find any reference to a file of that name in Google searches. Can you please open the MySQL client and run `SELECT @@version;` and tell us what it returns?

Comment: Have you used "Tune up utilities"?

Comment: It is Mysql version 5.6.21-log. It is in principle Mysql who generates the file, "tbs" reminds to tablespace

Comment: What is the result of ```show variables like 'innodb_data_file_path' ```? Maybe ```mysql -uuser -e"SHOW VARIABLES" | grep system```  will give you more information?!

Comment: THIS is my innodb_data_file_path, I was able to confirm that. And it has a size of 17GB